# CSS: Is it possible to break out of a container while keeping the layout

Tags: html, css, debugging, margin

I am coding a page which is supposed to be fullscreen on mobile. It will be displayed in a shopify store which has margins on the left and right. I want to remove these without touching the container of my html. Is this possible?

I have tried to change the position to absolute but this collapsed my footer.

Here is the width of the container:

```
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
```

Comment: Where's your code? It is difficult to help you without it...

Comment: @Helenesh Thank you for your Feedback! I edited the question.

Comment: What do you mean by not touching the container?

Comment: @Helenesh I do not want to change the width of the container, as this would change the container on all the other pages too. I would prefer to make the content of the container exceed the width of the container.

Comment: Which Shopify theme are you using? Maybe that theme uses a grid which has a 'fluid container' option like in Bootstrap.

Comment: @Helenesh I am using the Theme Turbo by OutOfTheSandbox. As far as I know, it has a 16 column grid. How would I trigger this fluid container option?

Answer (score 0):

CSS supports negative margins, if I'm reading your question correctly you have a parent container with margins and a child container you would like to reach outside the parent container. Something like this should work:

```
.parent {
   margin-left: 1em;
   margin-right: 1em;
}
.child {
   margin-left: -1em;
   margin-right: -1em;
}
```

Then change your negative margins to match those of the parent margins and you should be able to break out of the parent without changing the parent container.

Comment: I am sorry, I checked my themes code after posting this and the size of the container is not set by a margin, it is set by doing a width calculation: width: calc(100% - 40px); Is it possible to escape that?

Comment: There's still a margin there, even if it isn't set by margin. you should be able to get the desired result with margin-left: -20px; and margin-right: -20px;

Answer (score 0):

After researching the Turbo Theme by OutOfTheSandbox and inspecting the code of their [demo](https://turbo-theme.myshopify.com/), I found that adding the class `container full-width--true` should work:

```
    <div class="container full-width--true"> 
        // My full-width container 
    </div>
```

This sets the container width to 100%, thus taking the full width of the viewport.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My content is almost fullscreen now. There is a small gap on the right side. I don't have any margins in my code, which makes me wonder, where this comes from.

Comment: Inspect it then... This is the correct answer for a full width container, I have tested this myself. This code adds no margin or padding whatsoever and sets the width to 100%. Maybe it's a parent element adding the extra margin?